# ThreadLocks and Static Constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

**Given:**

A ASP.net Web api application hosted in IIS .
The application spawns about 30 app domains each for a plugin which does some external work.

The application serves a **lot of** users and runs most of the time very well, but some times (after days or even weeks) it becoms a sudden hang.

**Problem:**

One Webapplication has sometimes "hangs" which result in requiring to restart the w3wp.exe  .

After some examinations of dumps in this state we found out that at this moments there are lot of threads ( sometimes about 15.000).

In a normalcase we never observe more then one hundred threads.

The DebugDiag says that there is one thread blocking the others

[image]

Now we have seen that in thread 44 (and many many others; about 90%), have the same call at the end:

[image]

The Method itself doesn't have any locking or threading behavior.but it has one uncommon thing concerning its static constructor. The ctor looks like this:

```
   static TimeZoneHelper()
        {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(Resources.TimeZones))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(';');

                TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(parts[1]);

                timeZones[parts[0]] = timeZone;
            }
        }
}
```

Furthermore the debug analysis indicates that the application was in a active gc (and as you would potentially ask: we never ever manually trigger a gc.collect)
[image]

**Question**
Is there an evidence indicating that this type of code is problematic in a static ctor? Even if there is not task or threading code ? Perhaps something related to the GC progress itself (as the object is disposable, even if not having a dispose code?)

**TimeZoneHelper**

I created a gist containing the main methods of this class inlcuding the ctor and the method which was called `TimeZoneHelper.ToTimeZoneOffset`:

https://gist.github.com/Gentlehag/9d564555261da0e73366

The main thing the method results in is a Dictionary.TryGet (Which was created in the ctor)

---

Edit
Btw I also want to add that in each appdomain a assembly resolve event is bound.
The code can be seen here:

https://gist.github.com/Gentlehag/4726b6d888adb149684d

---

**Important Update**
I am a colleague and just want to add some more information. We also found another scenario which is very similar. I have the stacktrace from the thread that owns the block:

```
000000c898897560 00007ff8855b7e5d System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].FindEntry(System.__Canon)
000000c8988975d0 00007ff8855b7d34 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryGetValue(System.__Canon, System.__Canon ByRef)
000000c898897610 00007ff88f6152b3 GP.Components.Extensions.AppDomains.RemotingRunner.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(System.Object, System.ResolveEventArgs)
000000c8988978a0 00007ff886f7276c System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.String)
000000c898897bd0 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [GCFrame: 000000c898897bd0] 
000000c898899b78 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 000000c898899b78] System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
000000c898899c80 00007ff886f7224e System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Version, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
000000c898899d60 00007ff886f716c8 System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
000000c898899df0 00007ff885b932fb System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
000000c898899eb0 00007ff885b92ecb System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
000000c898899fa0 00007ff885b92b73 System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean)
000000c898899ff0 00007ff885b92014 System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
000000c89889a0a0 00007ff89914aa62 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.InitializeFromXml(System.String, System.String)
000000c89889a140 00007ff89914a838 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.Initialize(System.String)
000000c89889a1a0 00007ff899143be9 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.Initialize()
000000c89889a210 00007ff899123a27 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent+AgentSingleton.CreateInstance()
000000c89889a280 00007ff8991239c2 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Singleton`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.__Canon)
000000c89889a2c0 00007ff89912388b NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent..cctor()
000000c89889a700 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [GCFrame: 000000c89889a700] 
000000c89889ce88 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [PrestubMethodFrame: 000000c89889ce88] NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent.get_Instance()
000000c89889cef0 00007ff89912358c NewRelic.Agent.Core.AgentShim.GetTracer(System.String, UInt32, System.String, System.String, System.Type, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Object, System.Object[])
000000c89889d280 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000c89889d280]
```

It is not about the TimeZoneHelper class, but it is interesting that there is a common aspect: Both class load a resource in their static constructor (either the config file for NewRelic or the File with the TimeZones). So the scenario seems to be the following:

1. Multiple threads try to use the class
2. The first thread gets the lock for the static constructor and runs this constructor
3. A resource is loaded and the .NET runtime tries to load a resource assembly.
4. We catch the AssemblyResolve-event to load the resource assembly and cause a deadlock in some way, the question is how?

Comment: Even though the method has no locking or threading, as you say, please still post it. It may be calling a framework method that does use a lock under the covers. In general, if stack traces tell you a particular method is blocking, it's safe to assume that that method *really is blocking*. (The static constructor is a separate method with its own name (`.cctor`).) Also, the entire stack trace is more helpful than just the last frame.

Comment: I linked a gist with the code

Comment: My bad -- I missed the fact that the call is not from the method body but the `PrestubMethodFrame`, which does suggest a CLR internal lock being involved. More pertinent info you can add: the unmanaged call stack (as returned with `kb`), and especially of the thread that owns the lock (44 in the above example). If the call stack *is* the one of the thread owning the lock (I'm not sure if "44" is a thread ID here), you need to figure out what that thread is actually waiting on (what handle is passed to `ZwWaitForSingleObject`). The stack trace should help there.

Comment: Can you post the complete call stack of the thread that you think is the block leader?

Comment: Managed or unmanaged?  I can access the unmanaged tomorrow morning again.

Comment: Anything that you can get. So far the solution is not apparent. We need to dig.

Comment: What happens if you refactor the static constructor/methods into a class that you instantiate once?

Comment: The Problem is that this problem doesn't occur every time. There are days some times weeks when this error occurs

Comment: Do you have any unhandled exception processing mechanism? If you ever touch TimeZoneHelper inside an exception handling method, it would end up in recursion, because any subsequent call to a TimeZoneHelper's method would result in an TypeInitializerException. This could be also the case of a custom error page. Make sure that your custom error page never throws exceptions. There could be a kind of recursion otherwise.

Comment: At least we never noticed a StackoOverflowException and I also checked the code again. I am pretty sure, that we do not call TimeZoneHelper in any exception handler. (I am his colleague)

Comment: We have about 60 extensions. Each extension is running in its own app pool and will be loaded when the application starts but might be reloaded (unload the existing app domain and create a new one) when a new version of the extension will be deployed. We had the last issue this night at 2pm, just when we recycled the application pool of the web app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess on what happens.

UPDATE:
I think it's a recursion problem with AssemblyResolve event.
Based on comments, a stack overflow did not occur, but there still could be a recursion problem, so the answer still applies.

There is an indication that this bug depends on the order of accessing the resources. Most likely this happens when the first thing is an access to one of the static classes you mentioned.

When you access a resource for the first time, an AssemblyResolve event fires several times. Subsequent resource requests do not result in AssemblyResolve events. This can be demonstrated by following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Resolve {0}", eventArgs.Name);
    return null;
};
Console.WriteLine(Resource1.String1);
Console.WriteLine(Resource1.String1);
```

Result:

```
Resolve ConsoleApplication1.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru-RU, PublicKeyToken=null
Resolve ConsoleApplication1.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru-RU, PublicKeyToken=null
Resolve ConsoleApplication1.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru, PublicKeyToken=null
Resolve ConsoleApplication1.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=ru, PublicKeyToken=null
Value from resource
Value from resource
```

Logger is accessing the resources, and this is indicated by:

```
000000c898899ff0 00007ff885b92014 System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
000000c89889a0a0 00007ff89914aa62 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.InitializeFromXml(System.String, System.String)
000000c89889a140 00007ff89914a838 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.Initialize(System.String)
000000c89889a1a0 00007ff899143be9 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Config.ConfigurationLoader.Initialize()
000000c89889a210 00007ff899123a27 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent+AgentSingleton.CreateInstance()
000000c89889a280 00007ff8991239c2 NewRelic.Agent.Core.Singleton`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.__Canon)
000000c89889a2c0 00007ff89912388b NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent..cctor()
000000c89889a700 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [GCFrame: 000000c89889a700] 
000000c89889ce88 00007ff8e4b2a7f3 [PrestubMethodFrame: 000000c89889ce88] NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent.get_Instance()
000000c89889cef0 00007ff89912358c NewRelic.Agent.Core.AgentShim.GetTracer(System.String, UInt32, System.String, System.String, System.Type, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Object, System.Object[])
```

My conclusion here is that logger could be run successfully without AssemblyResolve any event bound for the first time, and would not ever cause an AssemblyResolve event, if it run for the first time this way.

If you access a resource for the first time from an AssemblyResolve, a recursive call happens, which leads to StackOverflowException. This is easy to model:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Resolve {0}", eventArgs.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(Resource1.String1);
    return null;
};

Console.WriteLine(Resource1.String1);
```

And there is a call to Logger:

```
catch
{
    context.RunnerLog.Error(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Failed to load assembly {0}.", args.Name));

    result = null;
}
```

There could be a difference, if logger was initialized before AssemblyResolve event was bound, or there was another condition that did not cause the logger to fire a failing AssemblyResolve event.

When you started with a call to a static class and have an exception in AssemblyResolve, and you supposed to be catching and logging that, the call to logger causes an access to a resource, and that one causes another assembly resolve and this recursion leads to stack overflow.

While first request has a lock on a static class constructor, if that operation was holding for a long time before the StackOverflowException, other requests are blocked, but it does not matter, because they would fail with TypeInitializationException. The latter would never happen, because domain would start to unload after the StackOverflowException anyway.

The fact that it's showing some dictionary Find method on top does not matter also - it's probably the last drop that contributed to a stack overflow.

One thing I would recommend to use another kind of logger inside the AssemblyResolve event handlers.

Another thing is that i would try to avoid any blocking IO requests in static constructors, such as a resource access or manual assembly loading. Just initialize the basic stuff inside, and use another concurrency mechanism for lazy initialization in the public methods themselves.

However, i don't think that the cause of the suspected stackoverflow have to do with the static constructors.

Also, the could be no suspected stack overflow if the recursion went too slowly for stackoverflow to occur. This way the domain could start unloading by other reasons - for example by some resource consumption guard of IIS, such as amount of threads or general memory consumption. This would be likely to happen if requests block for long time.

Comment: We are now aviable to remove the assembly resolve method. If you are right, then this error should not appear anymore, shouldn't it ?

Comment: I would start with reproducing the problem.

Comment: Create a small app, as in my proposed demo, replace a resource access with your logger (with a setup similar to your prod app). Replace the resource accesses (Console.WriteLine(Resource1.String1);) with RunnerLog.Error(); calls, and you should experience stackoverflow. Then you will be sure. If not, make sure the logger setup raises the an AssemblyResolve event, because that is the suspected cause.

Comment: We tried but we don't get this error. Also the logger doesn't imply IO, he just puts the data in some kind of a queue. after some investigation we don't  anymore the assembly resolve, so we completly removed it (which also reduces complexity)

Comment: Are you sure you have set up the logger only after setting up AssemblyResolve event? It's not the IO which cased the error, it's a resource access in the logger setup.

Comment: We have different logging mechanisms:

1. We use common logging with a custom adapter for Azure Tables. It is setup right after the start of the application. The logger put the entries in a queue and a separate thread uses the queue once per minute to flush the entries to azure tables, afaik there is no resource access involved, especially not in the thread that puts something to the queue. There is also no access to Web.config or some other config file.

2. We have NewRelic which hooks into requests and so on for tracing and is instantiated via a lazy singleton the first time it is needed.

Comment: As i see in the stack trace, the NewRelic one is accessing a resource. NewRelic.Agent.Core.Agent+AgentSingleton.CreateInstance() leads to System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString, that is the suspect. And when it's 'needed' for the first time only after the AssemblyResolve is bound, then it causes troubles. If you access the signleton right before the `AssemblyResolve +=` thing, there would be no problem. I suspect that is why you are not experiencing this problem if something is being logged before you add the event handler.

Comment: Might be, we couldnt reproduce it yet. Because we have multiple app domains the initialization can happen several times.